# Too many "&&"s in condition coding. The better codes?

Tags: c#, linq

The following code works as intended but seems inelegant.

```
.Where(x =>     x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Quick"))
            && !x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Brown"))
            && !x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Fox"))
            && !x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Jumps"))
            && !x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Lazy"))
            && !x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Dogs")))
```

As you can see, I am checking whether

- the XElement has exactly one attribute
- this attribute has the specified name

[Edit] My intention is..I want to make sure that the element has only one attribute. I mean only "Quick" attribute in this case. I know the count style though, the count does not distinguish its name.[/Edit]

[Edit2]I want elements if only if it has sigle attribute, nothing else.[/Edit2]

[Edit3]"x" is an element for instance..

```
<mySeg Quick="1" Brown="Two" Fox="None" Jumps="2016_En" Lazy="100" Dogs="Source">  //  I do not want this XElement
```

or

```
<mySeg Quick="2" Brown="Ten">  //  Nah.
```

or

```
<mySeg Quick="3">  // yes, this is one I'm looking for.
```

[Edit3]

[Edit4]
I guess, I have to use this one. Actually, it is the one I used before this post. I was thingking one shot.

```
x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Quick")) && x.Attributes().Count() == 1 //thanks Ryan
```

[Edit4]

Comment: First explain what you expect the code to do.

Comment: Your code is fine and elegant. The only question you need to ask yourself is: if the string has `Brown` can it also have the other ones? If not then you don't need to check the other conditions. Else your code is fine.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks I have Edited it.

Comment: please include more context.

Comment: If you are unhappy with the way your code looks you can use separate Where statements

Comment: @CodingYoshi I'm confusing with simple and/or logic. That is why I posted this one. Thanks.

Comment: `x.Attributes().Length`/`x.Attributes().Count`/`x.Attributes.Count()` `!= 1` doesn’t work? (What is `x`?)

Comment: I would wrap `x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Quick")` in a `boolean isAttrContain(Object x, String attr)`. Then your conditions is a bit shorter and readable. Less code duplicaiton.

Comment: @Ryan Yes. Kind of. But, your examples do not distinguish its name. thanks

Comment: @DanielA.White Edited..

Comment: @Jason: You’d check both… `x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Quick")) && x.Attributes().Count() == 1`, as a start. But there’s probably a better way. What’s `x`?

Comment: @DavidLee Don't know. The longer one ? ok, I'll try.

Comment: If you find `and/or` logic confusing, search for truth tables.

Comment: @Jason This question is confusing as heck.  The edits have only increased my confusion.

Comment: Is it possible, that x.Attributes contains more than the six values? If not, Ryans answer should work

Comment: What’s the actual type of `x`? Not “an element”, but a C# type with documentation or a description. Is it an `XElement`?

Comment: @Ryan Yes. You are right. C# XElement

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks, but not much helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to ensure that it contains one and only one of a list of attributes, and you can create the list of attributes you care about, you can intersect it with the object you're examining and see if the intersection is only one item:

```
var attributesICareAbout = new List<Attribute>
{
    AllAttributes.Attribute("Quick"),
    AllAttributes.Attribute("Brown"),
    AllAttributes.Attribute("Fox"),
    AllAttributes.Attribute("Jumps"),
    AllAttributes.Attribute("Lazy"),
    AllAttributes.Attribute("Dogs")
};

// To get all items that have only a single attribute from our list and no others:
.Where(x => x.Attributes().Intersect(attributesICareAbout).Count == 1);
```

To get the items that have a specific attribute and no others:

```
// To get all the items who have only a single "Quick" attribute:
.Where(x => x.Attributes().Count(a => a == AllAttributes.Attribute("Quick")) == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first gloss, you are testing

1. that a specific item is present
2. that *none* of a set of other items are present

Specifically, you are looking for a succinct way to express "none of these".

Rufus almost answered this question. Set up a list using his approach.

```
var exclusions = new string[] { "Brown", "Fox" , "Jumps", "Lazy", "Dogs" };
```

Now you can test for the absence of this entire set. Remember that "none of" is the same as "not any of". We intersect the set of attribute names with the exclusion set and check whether it is empty using `!` and `.Any()`.

```
.Where(x => x.Attributes().Contains(x.Attribute("Quick"))
  && !a.Attributes().Select(a => a.Name).Intersect(exclusions).Any())
```

### However

You clarified the requirements to

- XElement has exactly one attribute
- This attribute has a specific name

and since you already credited "Ryan" with the obvious solution to this much simpler question here I stop.

---

You are doing set based comparison. Here's some homework.

- [The `join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/join-operations)
- Get a copy of [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and use that to experiment as you learn to use Linq effectively.
- [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Join as a lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) is messy. I prefer the inline syntax for joins.

You may also find it useful to explore the fact that you can combine Count with Where - Count can take a lambda expression that resolves to a Boolean, just like Where, and the result is the number of items that satisfied the condition. You can use this to count along several different dimensions in a single compound condition.